# Unable to import mlflow, getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlflow'

Tags: python-3.x, docker, machine-learning, python-module, mlflow

Unable to import `mlflow` in a .py script.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlflow'
```

The script runs in a `python:3.7-stretch Docker` container

Use `requirements.txt` to pip install packages.

```
(...)
sqlalchemy==1.4.1
psycopg2==2.8.6
mlflow==1.18.0
```

```
RUN pip3 install --default-timeout=5000 --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver -r /root/requirements.txt
```

Can see that it is installed.

```
root@abc:~# pip uninstall mlflow
Found existing installation: mlflow 1.18.0
Uninstalling mlflow-1.18.0:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/bin/mlflow
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow-1.18.0.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/*
Proceed (y/n)? n
```

Can do an import from python shell.

```
root@abc:~# python
Python 3.7.10 (default, Feb 16 2021, 19:46:13)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>> import mlflow
>>>
```

But no joy when running from .py script.

Other packages installed from `requirements.txt` can be imported.

Any ideas what is wrong ?